# HTML Table within DIV element keeps moving around as browser resizes

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

I am trying to produce a webpage with a login form. The login form components are placed in a table wich is inside a `<div>` element; it's all done but now I'm facing resizing issues: whenever I resize my browser, the table elements keep moving around and it doesn't looks nice...
I want the login form to be fixed and not to move around if I resize the browser in width or height (or both, in diagonal).

My HTML template code can be seen next:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>GIETINF | Management</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/onClick.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <form method="POST" action="login.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right"><p id="text">E-mail:</p></td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="user@server.pt" onFocus="this.value=''">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right"><p id="text">password:</p></td>
                      <td align="left"><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <table id="little_box">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2"><input type="reset" value="Reset values"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <table id="little_box2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left"> <input type="submit" onClick="OpenEmailtoadmin()" value="Register"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div> 
    </body>

</html>
```

And my CSS for this page:

```
body
{
background-image:url('../images/logo.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 20% 0%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #3A4147;
background-size: fixed;
}



input[type="text"] {
border: 2px solid #F7921F;
background: #ffffff;
color:#969999;
}

input[type="password"] {
border: 2px solid #F7921F;
background: #ffffff;
color:#969999;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background: #341243;
border: 2px solid black;
color:#F7921F;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
border: 2px solid black;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);-moz-opacity:.5;opacity:.5;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
input[type="submit"]:focus  {
border: thin #000000 solid;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
input[type="submit"]:focus:hover {
border: thin #000000 solid;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;opacity:1;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
input[type="reset"] {
background: #341243;
border: 2px solid black;
color:#F7921F;
}
input[type="reset"]:hover {
border: 2px solid black;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);-moz-opacity:.5;opacity:.5;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
input[type="reset"]:focus  {
border: thin #000000 solid;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
input[type="reset"]:focus:hover {
border: thin #000000 solid;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;opacity:1;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}

#registration_button {
background: #341243;
border: 2px solid black;
color:#F7921F;
}
#registration_button:hover {
border: 2px solid black;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);-moz-opacity:.5;opacity:.5;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
#registration_button:focus  {
border: thin #000000 solid;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}
#registration_button:focus:hover {
border: thin #000000 solid;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1;opacity:1;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
}

#box
{
position: absolute; 
width: 50%;
height: 30%;
left: 50%;
top: 35%;

}

#little_box
{
position: relative;
width: 20%;
height: 10%;
left: 15.4%;
top: 35%;
}

#little_box2
{
position: relative;
width: 20%;
height: 10%;
left: 24.4%;
top: 35%;
}

#box_error
{
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 30%;
left: 39%;
top: 65%;
}

#text
{
font-family:arial;
color:white;
font-size:14px;
}
```

I'm sorry for the long text; I saw other issues like this solved but I don't seem to get a nice solution out of them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #box{
        height: 30%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: use this css to get a centered form

Comment: You want to have a fixed centered div in the middle of the page right?

Comment: Not really. I want to have the power to control de div element around my web page but I want it fixed, I don't want it to move around as my browser gets resized. It's all good when the browser is maximized but if I resize it, the login form moves around and gets unrecognizable.

Comment: ok, than you have to use absolute values not in percent. The positions are relative to your window size...

Comment: Thank you so much wormonic, that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Because your table don't have width:

```
   <table style="width:1000px;">
         <tr>
             <td style="width:20%"></td>
             <td style="width:20%"></td>
             <td style="width:20%"></td>
             <td style="width:20%"></td>
             <td style="width:20%"></td>
         </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: when I give width to tags they dont move with browser resize. Try to give width to <td> tags for first row too, see my update

Comment: I used absolute values in pixel units like wormonic told me to and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help though!